# passing json information to child

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Im trying to pass this jsons data into a props that i can use on the featured component of my app but every time i try to grab the information i get a results undefined

This is the main app component

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    items:[],
    didLoad: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/4971683/calendar.json?apikey={mykey}"
    const response =  await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({items:data});
    console.log(this.state.items)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header/>
        <Element name = 'Featured'>
          <Featured data1 = {this.state.items}/>
        </Element>
        <Element name = "Venue_info">
          <VenueInfo/>
        </Element>
        <Element name = "Highlights">
          <Highlights/>
        </Element>
        <Element name = "Pricing">
          <Pricing/>
        </Element>
        <Element name = "Location">
          <Location/>
        </Element>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the featured component that i want to use the api information on

```
const Featured = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div style = {{position: 'relative'}}>

            <Carrousel/>
            <div className = "artist_name">
                <div className = "wrapper">
                    Arianna Grande
                </div>
            </div>
            <TimeUntil deadline = {props.data1.resultsPage.results.event[0].start.datetime}/>
        </div>


    );
};
```

just used mykey as a placeholder but i do have an apikey for this api.

Comment: Is api returning undefined?
If so your problem is in url string.

`const url = \`https://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/4971683/calendar.json?apikey=${mykey}\``

This url uses interpolation to insert key.

Notice \` character instead of your " at start and end of url string. Also you need to add $  before {mykey}.

Comment: My key is not the problem i still receive the data returned as a json element that im trying to retrieve the date of the start of an event. the {mykey} is a placeholder for my api key including the curly braces

Comment: So... Is console.log(props) logging undefined in console?
Is TimeUntil component throwing error?

Share more details.

Imo there might be an error in TimeUntil passed props. There is no such thing like `props.data1` in passed props. There is a chance you are missing `[ ]`.

Comment: I have tried this solution by @nir99 but it does not help I have decided to truncate the data in the start of my app.js and pass the small deadline data into the child component instead. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

in the state you declare item as a array `items = []` , so you need to access it as a array not as a object ,

```
const Featured = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div style = {{position: 'relative'}}>
            <Carrousel/>
            <div className = "artist_name">
                <div className = "wrapper">
                    Arianna Grande
                </div>
            </div>
            <TimeUntil deadline = 
                  {props.data1[0].resultsPage.results.event[0].start.datetime}/>
        </div>


    );
};
```

Comment: this still did not work and gave me a resultsPage undefined error. I have decided to chunk the data in my main app.js and pass that information instead of the entire json file and now it works. Thank you for your help though